# How to use Amazon RDS with Kohana's ORM

Tags: orm, kohana-3, amazon-rds

Is there any way to use Kohana's ORM with Amazon RDS?

I found the Amazon PHP SDK but I'm not sure how to plug it into Kohana so that the ORM uses it. I also couldn't find any Kohana module for Amazon RDS. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  I have this exact configuration for my website.

In your AWS management console, you will need to get the "endpoint" of your RDS server. The name is quite long and begins with the name of your DB instance. (See the code below for example)

Next, open your database configuration file: `application/config/database.php`

In the 'default' configuration, change your hostname to the endpoint. Also change the database, username and password to whatever yours is set up with:

```
'default' => array
    (
            'type'       => 'mysql',
            'connection' => array(
                    /**
                     * The following options are available for MySQL:
                     *
                     * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
                     * string   database     database name
                     * string   username     database username
                     * string   password     database password
                     * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
                     *
                     * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
                     */
                    'hostname'   => 'your-db-instance.njgo7sn43.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
                    'database'   => 'db_name',
                    'username'   => 'username',
                    'password'   => 'SuperCaliFrajilisticExpiAliDocious',
                    'persistent' => FALSE,
            ),
            'table_prefix' => '',
            'charset'      => 'utf8',
            'caching'      => FALSE,
            'profiling'    => TRUE,
    ),
```

Also, in your `application/bootstrap.php` file, make sure to UN-comment the database module:

```
Kohana::modules(array(
    'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access
    'orm'        => MODPATH.'orm',        // Object Relationship Mapping
));
```

The ORM module is optional but very nice to use.

Hope this helps!